# How to create a new group policy from an existing or exported GPT file, using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, commandlet

What I did so far:

1. I have created a group policy (a custom one) under
   'Local Computer Policy' -> 'User Configuration' -> 'xyz folder' -> SomeCustomPolicy. The policy *SomeCustomPolicy* is created with the settings I wanted to create.
2. I right clicked on *SomeCustomPolicy* and chose the option 'Save as Template', gave a name *SomeCustomPolicy*. Template is created and I can see this in "Templates" Tab next to the "Policies" Tab.
3. I right clicked on the template SomeCustomPolicy and selected 'Export', saved the output to 'SomeCustomPolicy.gpt'

Can I programmatically create a new policy with the 'SomeCustomPolicy.gpt' using powershell ?

I found commandlets for importing and exporting, but I wanted to create a new policy from an existing GPT file.